# Using Accented character in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, internationalization, pythonwin, unicodedecodeerror

I am trying to export a map using Python/ArcPy script. The problem that the title of the exported map containts somthing like "A(c)" instead of the accent "é" I wrote. The date (dt) is printed (in french) with no problem.
This part of my scripts looks like:

```
    txt1="Densité  \n"+ dt
    elmts[1].text=txt1
```

I am using Python 2.7, ArcGIS 10.2, Notepad++ as text editor and pythonWin IDE.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a codepage issue. Make sure the script uses UTF-8.

Comment: Yes but I already tried to add  this line in the top of my script:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: That might just be complicating matters, if The editor is writing something other than UTF-8.

Comment: Try u"Densité  \n".

Comment: @fatih_dur I tried to do that but it gives the eror:

Rdmt_espece_date=u"Densit頠\n"+ dt
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I finally find the solution. The problem was in the passage from the Notepad++ editor to PythonWin where the accented char (é) is strangely changed to the above mentioned characters. The script is actually changed. So I changed it back to 'é' in the PythonWin editor, save it and run it and it works. Thank you

Comment: @MahfoudB, please feel free to give your last comment (with a bit more context) as the answer to the question and accept it. That way people will check out one possible cause and also this question is closed as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The "Ã©" characters that appeared in the exported map instead of the accented char "é" that I want, came from the change of the written script itself not in  the way PythonWin compilate the code. I scripted my code using Notepad++ and the concerned part of the code was written like this:

```
Rtxt1="Densité  \n"+ dt
elmts[1].text=txt1
```

But when I tried to open th script and run it under PythonWin I found that it was changed to:

```
Rtxt1="DensitÃ©  \n"+ dt
elmts[1].text=txt1
```

So I changed it back to "é" in the PythonWin editor, run the script and it worked with no problem. 
I don't really know what exactly happen when going from Notepad++ to PythonWin but I think they don't treat accented chacters in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

`ArcMap` and `ArcGIS Pro` works with the following encoding `cp1252`.

You need to encode your strings by doing this:

```
"Densité".encode('cp1252')
```

*n.b the above solution, works both in ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap*

You may need to `decode` the result of `encode` in order to get an `str` (`'Densité'`) instead of `bytes` (`b'Densité'`).

For ArcGIS Pro 2.X / ArcGIS For server <11 :

```
"Densité".encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
```

For ArcGIS Pro 3.X / ArcGIS For server 11+ :

```
"Densité".encode('cp1252').decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

*n.b for some reason none of the previous line works in both environnement*